# Implementing material (mtl) files into objects (obj) in LWJGL/OpenGL

Tags: opengl, java, textures, lwjgl, materials

I have an object loader that takes in textures, but when I try making some textures, they never turn out exactly how I want.

I found out that a lot of them take a colour I want in one place and put it onto a different place where I don't want that colour.

I have been using a debug UV layout texture that has numbers and letters on it, like A1 and so on, and have been using that to help texture the objects. A lot of times, the numbers are shared in different places in the texture, and usually it's where I don't want them to be.

Also, it takes lot longer to texture my models than to just make the object and colour it regularly... So how would I be able to add a materials into my Object Loader?

Here's the Object Loader code:

```js
package renderEngine;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import models.RawModel;

public class OBJLoader {
    
    public static RawModel loadObjModel(String fileName, Loader loader) {
        FileReader fr = null;
      try {
        fr = new FileReader(new File("res/objects/"+fileName+".obj"));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.err.println("Could not read file!");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        List<Vector2f> textures = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        float[] verticesArray = null;
        float[] normalsArray = null;
        float[] textureArray = null;
        int[] indicesArray = null;
        try {
            while(true) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                if(line.startsWith("v ")) {
                    Vector3f vertex = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]),Float.parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
                    vertices.add(vertex);
                }else if(line.startsWith("vt ")) {
                    Vector2f texture = new Vector2f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]));
                    textures.add(texture);
                }else if(line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                    Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]),Float.parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
                    normals.add(normal);
                }else if(line.startsWith("f ")) {
                    textureArray = new float[vertices.size()*2];
                    normalsArray = new float[vertices.size()*3];
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            while(line!=null) {
                if(!line.startsWith("f ")) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    continue;
                }
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                String[] vertex1 = currentLine[1].split("/");
                String[] vertex2 = currentLine[2].split("/");
                String[] vertex3 = currentLine[3].split("/");
                
                processVertex(vertex1,indices,textures,normals,textureArray,normalsArray);
                processVertex(vertex2,indices,textures,normals,textureArray,normalsArray);
                processVertex(vertex3,indices,textures,normals,textureArray,normalsArray);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }       
            reader.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        verticesArray = new float[vertices.size()*3];
        indicesArray = new int [indices.size()];
        
        int vertexPointer = 0;
        for(Vector3f vertex:vertices) {
            verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.x;
            verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.y;
            verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.z;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<indices.size();i++) {
            indicesArray[i] = indices.get(i);
        }
        return loader.loadToVAO(verticesArray, textureArray, indicesArray);
    }
    
    private static void processVertex(String[] vertexData, List<Integer> indices,List<Vector2f> textures, List<Vector3f> normals,  
        float[] textureArray, float[] normalsArray) {
        int currentVertexPointer = Integer.parseInt(vertexData[0]) - 1;
        indices.add(currentVertexPointer);
        Vector2f currentTex = textures.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[1])-1);
        textureArray[currentVertexPointer*2] = currentTex.x;
        textureArray[currentVertexPointer*2+1] = 1 - currentTex.y;
        Vector3f currentNorm = normals.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[2])-1);
        normalsArray[currentVertexPointer*3] = currentNorm.x;
        normalsArray[currentVertexPointer*3+1] = currentNorm.y;
        normalsArray[currentVertexPointer*3+2] = currentNorm.z;
    }

}
```

And here's a little thing I have for material:

```js
package textures;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;

public class Material 
{
    public Texture texture;
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Vector3f ambient, diffuse, specular;
    public float shininess;
    public int shader;
}
```

So how would I use that so it takes those in the OBJLoader, so I don't have to bother with textures anymore?

Here's the object loader in use:

[image: Object loader in use]

Comment: It looks like your `.mtl` file is itself relying on a texture. So you might have to solve your UV unwrapping problem in the end anyway. If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to associate different parts/sub-objects of the model with different materials that are a different solid colour - so for instance the legs of the model could use a blue material while the head uses a yellow material? So it's not so much how to import the `.mtl` file you need help with, but how to associate different parts of the mesh with different material values?

Comment: I don't have any .mtl imported into my thingy the material class right now does nothing but yah right now the objects rely on having a texture......and its not really that simple this object wasn't probably best to show its just some random I made but I mean my other objects I can never get them to look the way I want also I just would rather use material then make textures for each thing as it would actually have them look how I want and also save alot of time..... so no I do want the .mtl file but if possible would like to be able to also texture if I need to for something like water........

Comment: I mean like the material class in the package textures just exists like there is nothing pulling anything from it or using it in anyway right now also  none of my things right now are using .mtl file because I don't have a way to use them so everything right now is just .png textures... and to clarify I want to move away or only use the .png textures when needed and mostly use materials (mtl) file for my objects sense I made them with material in mind....... so yah that is like kinda like what I mean with the post above this one its like 100% textures right now and would rather it be material

Comment: this is bascially why I want to be able to use materials instead of textures sometimes textures are useful but i would rather just it be only material if I had to pick one or the other......... https://ibb.co/Tk9mn0b you can see how much cleaner the material looks versus the texture.......